# How to use a variable value as an object key in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var work = 'sample';

{ 
    "publish": {
        work: "done"
    }
}
```

Initially the value of work is `sample`. If the value of work changes dynamically how can I pass the variable `work` into the object?

Comment: When you say the value of work changes dynamically, are you saying that if it's value is set by other functions, operations?

Comment: This is not JSON - the question is mis-tagged.

Answer (score 3):

I assume your object to be named `obj`,

```
var obj={ 
         "publish": {}
        }

obj.publish[work]= "done";
```

using square brackets you can define the property using a variable.

So the object will now become

```
{ 
  "publish": {
      "sample": "done"
  }
}
```

---

```js
var work = 'sample';

var obj = {
  "publish": {}
}

obj.publish[work] = "done";

document.write(JSON.stringify(obj))
```

See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/naeemshaikh27/0vso9ppe/)

Answer (score -2):

```
//try this
var work = "sample";
var yourJSON = { "publish": { "work": work }};

work = "updated sample";
yourJSON.publish.work = work;
```

Answer (score -2):

In your JSON structure, "work" is not in quotation marks. This means the word "work" does not function as a key itself -- only the **value** of the variable "work" works as a key.

In this respect, either your JSON or your variable declaration above is misleading.

If you meant this:

```
{ "publish": { "work": "done" } }
```

Then changing the value of "work" key is as simple as:

```
myNewStructure = {"publish": {"work": work}}
```